# Getting first element from a child prop in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My `Images.js` is as follows:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import axios from "axios"; 
import styled from "styled-components";
import ImageSlider_1 from "./ImageSlider_1";

const url = "https://hp-api.onrender.com/api/characters";

function Images() {   
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);   
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);   
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCharacters = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios(url);
        const data = await response.data;

        data.map((character) => {
          if (character.image.localeCompare("")) {
            setCharacters((characters) => [...characters, character]);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
        console.log(error);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchCharacters();   }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ImageSlider_1 characters={characters} />
      {/* <Carousel_Swiper characters={characters} /> */}
    </Wrapper>   ); }

const Wrapper = styled.section``;

export default Images;
```

My `ImageSldier_1.js` is as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

function ImageSlider_1({ characters }) {
  console.log(characters[0].image);

  // const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState(characters[0].image);
    
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {characters.map((character) => {
        return (
          <img src={character.image} alt={character.name} key={character.id} />
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const Wrapper = styled.section``;

export default ImageSlider_1;
```

I am not sure why `characters[0].image` gives me error as this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'image')

However, when I do `console.log(characters);` instead, it shows me there are 25 items.

I can do `characters.map((character) => console.log(character.image));` to display each of the image link, but then I need to set first image in the state variable:

```js
const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState(characters[0].image);
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can do: characters.map((character) => console.log(character.image));

You can use the `Array#map` function since `characters **is** an array.

> I am not sure why characters[0].image gives me error as this:

If `characters` is an empty array (`[]`), the first element of it (`[0]`) will be equal to `undefined`. And if it's `undefined`, trying to access `image` property (`.image`) will result in an error, since `undefined` **does not** have such property.

You could use *optional chaining* (`?`) to secure if `characters[0]` is `undefined`:

```
console.log(characters[0]?.image);
```

To set the `state` value, you should add `useEffect` to listen to `characters` changes and if it's populated, set the `image`.

```
const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
   setSliderData(characters[0]?.image ?? null);
}, [characters]);
```

Comment: Yeah. I know that but using optional chaining does not solve the problem when I need to initialize the state variable with the first image. Please note that console.log(characters[0]?.image); is not the issue. The main issue is I need to set the initialize the state variable with the first image. I am just using console.log(...) to verify there is no data available.

Comment: @Joy You can use `useEffect` for it. Updated answer.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. Your solution is as kind as your name.. :)

Comment: You might as well not set the initial state and just use `undefined`. `const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState();` and `setSliderData(characters[0]?.image)`.

Answer (score 0):

`characters` is initially an empty array in the parent `Images` component:

```js
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
```

So on the initial render cycle the value `[]` is passed to `ImageSlider_1` as a prop value until the `useEffect` hook in `Images` runs and fetches and updates the `characters` state and rerenders itself and its sub-ReactTree. There's no zero'th element to access an `image` property of and the error is thrown.

Now while you ***could*** store the passed `characters[0].image` into local state, using a `useEffect` hook to synchronize it, this is actually considered a React anti-pattern. Don't store the passed prop values in local state, and don't store derived state in local state. Just reference the passed prop value directly and compute the derived state.

```
function ImageSlider_1({ characters = [] }) {
  const sliderData = characters[0]?.image;
    
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {characters.map((character) => {
        return (
          <img src={character.image} alt={character.name} key={character.id} />
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Just about 100% of the time if you catch that you've coded a `useState`/`useEffect` combo you should ***really*** use the `useMemo` hook.

Instead of

```
function ImageSlider_1({ characters = [] }) {
  const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState(characters[0]?.image);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSliderData(characters[0]?.image);
  }, [characters]);
    
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

use

```
function ImageSlider_1({ characters = [] }) {
  const sliderData = useMemo(() => characters[0]?.image, [characters]);
    
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```